# Get properties from string miltilevel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want get value of laravel model my this

```
$key = "name";
$this->$key;   //returns the name
```

but, i want get multilevel values, like this

```
$key = "role->name";
$this->$key;   //returns nothing
```

what i can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to access the property of a property. Don't put both property names into the same variable. You can use two variables instead:

```
$first_level_property = "role";
$second_level_property = "name";
$this->$first_level_property->$second_level_property
```

[More examples](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php) of how to access property values.

Comment: but, i need it with one line

Comment: @NicolIsraelOlveraAcosta If your solution works go ahead and put it in as an answer to this question. Answering your own question is encouraged here.